# Turn off framerate on metal api for ios

Tags: metal, metalkit

I have an app that only needs to refresh the draw when panning on the screen is detected. For that reason I don't do the rendering in the drawInMTKView method, instead I have a method that is triggered when panning is detected and I do the required encoding there. 
How can I turn off the framerate (and with it the automatic calls on drawInMTKView)?

Answer (score 2):

You can still do your rendering on-demand in `drawInMTKView:` by setting the view's `paused` and `enableSetNeedsDisplay` properties both to `true`. Then, whenever you call the `setNeedsDisplay` method on the view, the draw method will be called as part of the ordinary display update loop.

Answer (score 0):

The property *enableSetNeedsDisplay* controls the behaviour of the view delegate. Set it to NO to avoid the delegate being triggered by setNeedsDisplay. 
Set the *paused* property to YES to avoid internal the callback triggered by internal timer.

```
mtkView.enableSetNeedsDisplay = NO;
mtkView.paused = YES;
```

When you want to draw, call the draw method. This will call drawInMTKView:

```
[mtkView draw];
```